# Cassandra modeling pattern

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I'm new to Cassandra, and I've been reading all I can and experimenting.

I've come across documentation that say you can can create 1 table per query, if you like.  So if I have a "Customer" record that has 4 different fields that I need to query by, then I can to create 4 different tables to do that.

Then I came across a feature called a "Batch" which seems say that I can make 4 updates happen transactionally if I put them in a batch.

But I can't find anything clear in the documentation that pulls all of the pieces together and says "You SHOULD create 1 table per query, and you SHOULD use a Batch to keep all of those query tables in sync.  This is the best practice."

Is this the best practice?  For a newbie, I could do with a little less "CAN" and a little more "SHOULD"  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using materialized views?  This is a new feature in Cassandra 3.0 that could meet your use case nicely, you can have a base table and then create a view off that table for each query.  For example, using [this blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/materialized-view-performance-in-cassandra-3-x) as an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int
 );

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW users_by_name AS 
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE username IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id);
```

When you insert data into users, the data is also propagated to views.  However, it's not exactly transactional (getting a successful response for the write does not mean it's been propagated to the views yet, but they will be eventually), but it may reduce burden on the client side and should take care of any concerns about the tables/views being in sync.

Comment: Oh wow!  No, I hadn't come across materialized views in the tutorials.  Those look like a good option!  From the blog article you referenced (thanks for that too) it seems there is about a 10% performance penalty per Materialized View.  But using a BATCH seems to have a performance penalty too.   

I know it's relational-thinking to expect data consistency, but in real world scenarios, a lack of consistency can eventually be so costly that it's worth taking a penalty of either the MV or Batch, but MV is much better it seems.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You should not use batch. There are two big reasons:

- It's slower
- It could fail and if this happens: All your data are lost.

Better: Split everything into a different query. If you need a successful query on all nodes, use a consistency level of ALL or QUORUM. More here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html

You can read here more about this feature. How the batch works: https://inoio.de/blog/2016/01/13/cassandra-to-batch-or-not-to-batch/

But there's a use case for batches: If you already sent some insert queries with the same partition key and these queries are all still in progress, buffer the next queries and execute it as a batch if you got a successful response for the previous queries. With this, you can prevent too high loads on your database.

Edit:
One thing that I forgot: You wrote about create statements. I think neither batch nor ALL/QOURUM is important for creating statements. Usually, you don't dynamically create tables and insert, at the same time, new rows to this table. Usually: You create a new table in your dev environment, changes your application and, after your testing, you create a new table in your production environment. After a time you're deploying a new version of your application. In this time, you can be sure that the new table is created on every node. Some frameworks provide this dynamic creating of tables but I think it's better to control this by hand. It's too dangerous to do this with code. Maybe someone misspelled a table or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on batch!  They aren't as good as I was hoping.  :)  But I still do like the atomicity...because losing ALL of the data in a batch would be much better than losing some of the data.  For most applications I've worked on, data loss is preferable to data inconsistency.  At least with data loss you can raise and exception and try the whole thing over later.  With partial updates, your data slowly turns to soup over time, from my experience.  But maybe I work on weird apps.  :)